# VBA - how to get address (folder) of recently copied file from clipboard under Windows 32-bit using VBA?

Tags: vba, windows, winapi, outlook, clipboard

How to get address (folder) of the most recently copied file from clipboard under Windows 32-bit using VBA (Outlook or Excel 2007) ? This is needed element for macro which will paste hyperlink to file instead of file itself into e-mail message or some Excel file.

I've found that thread about working with windows cliboard with VBA : http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/do-clear-copy-clipboard-using-vba-t1642294.html it seems to be quite useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to [query the clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649039.aspx) for its current data, looking for [standard formats](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776902.aspx) like `CF_HDROP` or `CFSTR_FILENAME` that you can extract a file path from.

Whether you can actually do that in VBA directly, I do not know. You might need to write a separate native solution in C++ or VB and wrap it in a COM object for VBA to then use.

Comment: It's possible to do in VBA because it offer access to Windows' dll's.